# How to extract values from onCall firebase function and load them in future builder

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-functions

i have a onCall cloud function which is returning

```
      resp.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(entities));
```

In my flutter app, i have created this future to get values from it.

```
Future<void> dataDriven(String filename) async {
  HttpsCallable callable = 
  FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('fruitsType');
  final results = await callable;
  final datE = results.call(<String, dynamic>{
 
    'filename': 'filename',
  });
  final dataF = await datE.then((value) => value.data);
  print (dataF);   
}
```

It is successfully printing the response which is as per expectation. but my snapshot is always returning null. It is not even reaching hasData stage. Please help.

Response;

```
[{"name":"banana","type":"fruit","count":0,"color":"yellow"},{{"name":"apple","type":"fruit","count":2,"color":"red"}]

       FutureBuilder(
        future: dataDriven('fruits.txt'),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
  return const Center(
  child: Text('An error has occurred!'),
  );
  } else {
    final data = snapshot.data;
    return Text(data.toString());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are some issues that need to be fixed (See comments in code).

```
// Set the correct return type (not void because you are returning data)
Future<String> dataDriven(String filename) async {
  HttpsCallable callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('fruitsType');

  // You can just call the function here with await
  final result = await callable.call({
    // Remove the quotes on the filename value
    'filename': filename,
  });

  // Don't forget to return the data
  return result;   
}
```

I suggest reading up on the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) about calling cloud functions from a flutter app and basic dart syntax.